# Tensorflow variable initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    x = process_x(x_data[i])[:std_size]
    y = word[i][:std_size]
    x_split = tf.split(0, time_step_size, x)
    outputs, state = tf.nn.rnn(rnn_cell, x_split, state)

    prediction = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, rnn_size])
    real = tf.reshape(y, [-1])
    ratio = tf.ones([time_step_size * batch_size])

    loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([prediction], [real], [ratio])
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)/batch_size
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
    step = 0
    print state
    while step < 1000:
        sess.run(train)
        step+=1
    result = sess.run(tf.arg_max(prediction, 1))
    print result, [t for t in result] == y
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

If source code is like above, rnn_cell and state is initialized in every steps in `for` loops?
If I want to use state in other training case then I have to reuse it. So rnn_cell and state should be initialized at first only not after that.
I can't imagine how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have to separate your computational graph part with the session running part. what you are doing now is not how tensorflow usually works. maybe try this:

```
rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
x_split = tf.split(0, time_step_size, x)
outputs, state = tf.nn.rnn(rnn_cell, x_split, state)

prediction = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, rnn_size])
real = tf.reshape(y, [-1])
ratio = tf.ones([time_step_size * batch_size])

loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([prediction], [real], [ratio])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)/batch_size
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(len(x_data)):
    x = process_x(x_data[i])[:std_size]
    y = word[i][:std_size]

step = 0
while step < 1000:
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x_split:x, real:y})
    step+=1
    result = sess.run(tf.arg_max(prediction, 1))
    print result, [t for t in result] == y
```

your code may have some design problem, but the point is separating your graph design with your "training".